# Permission based authorization .net identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, user-permissions

I am new to .NET, MVC & Identity Framework.  I noticed the identity framework allows for securing individual controller actions via annotations.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id){
    //edit action
}
```

I would like to secure certain actions based on user permissions.

**Example :** A blog application where only the user who created a blog post can edit.

With this in mind, is it possible to perform either option below?  If so, are there resources and examples on how to best achieve?

```
[Authorize(Entity = "Entry", Permission = "Edit", Id = Id)]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id){
    //edit action
}
```

or

```
[BlogEntryPermission(Permission = "Edit", Id = Id)]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id){
    //edit action
}
```

Where blog `Id` is captured from the request.

Any information or direction on permission based authentication would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement your custom `AuthorizationAttribute` where you will specify your parameters and can get a `blogId` from request

```
public class AuthorizeEntryPermission : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public string Permission { get; set; }

        public AuthorizeEntryPermission(){
        }

        public AuthorizeEntryPermission(string Permission)
        {
            this.Permission = Permission;
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
             var id = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Id"];
             //check your permissions
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                // ** IMPORTANT **
                // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
                // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
                // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
                // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
                // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
                // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

                HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
                cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
            }
            else
            {
                //handle no permission
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
            validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }
    }
```

Then use it like this:

```
[AuthorizeEntryPermission(Permission = "Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id){
    //edit action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Now running into an issue when trying to access the path variable.  var id = httpContext.Request.Form["BlogId"]; will not work for path params defined like this : /BlogPost/Edit/1.  Is there a clean way to access this variable?  context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ElementAt(2).Value works but not sure is something I want to rely on.

Comment: @croteau You can use `context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Id"]`

Answer (score 1):

MVC has roles built-in. You can make the roles as granular as you  need - essentially making them like permissions. For example, you could make role names like:

- EditBlogPost
- AddBlogPost
- ViewBlogPost

Then you can set the roles up on your controller using the built-in AuthorizeAttribute.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AddBlogPost")]
public ActionResult Add(){
    //add action
}

[Authorize(Roles = "AddBlogPost")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(BlogModel model){
    //add action
}

[Authorize(Roles = "EditBlogPost")]
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id){
    //edit action
}

[Authorize(Roles = "EditBlogPost")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(BlogModel model){
    //edit action
}

[Authorize(Roles = "ViewBlogPost")]
public ActionResult View(){
    //view action
}
```

Then it is just a matter of assigning the different roles to each user in your database.

Comment: You have to be careful with this approach, though. There is a maximum size to the cookie limit. In a large application you might have thousands of granular roles

Comment: Good point. However, the OP said he wanted permissions for a blog - implying that there are not that many controllers to manage. But if there are a large number of permissions I agree that customizing the AuthorizeAttribute would be a better way to go.

Comment: @Shoe - Actually, you don't necessarily have to store the roles inside of the cookie. You could just set it up to load them per request or cache them per user. Or, you could set the roles up with bitwise IDs so the only thing that you would need to store in the cookie is a single long number.

Comment: Yes you could, but the default Authorize attribute checks the claims for them. You'd have to customize that as you said in your previous comment.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about this approach as well and I think what @NightOwl888 was getting at is that for this approach to work with the OP's situation, you would need one role for each combination of each permission AND each individual post.

Comment: Downvoted; this smells a lot like abusing roles as if they were [permissions](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Permission-Management), it also doesn't tell how to implement different permissions for each blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your problem solved till now. But worth it to add a new solution. I've implemented a **Permission-based extension** for Microsoft Identity 2 membership system. It's an open source project and you can access to the repository here:

https://github.com/Arminkhodaei/Identity-Permission-Extension

Usage:

First approach:

```
// GET: /Manage/Index
[AuthorizePermission(Name = "Show_Management", Description = "Show the Management Page.")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    //...
}
```

Second approach:

```
// GET: /Manage/Users
public async Task<ActionResult> Users()
{
    if (await HttpContext.AuthorizePermission(name: "AllUsers_Management", description: "Edit all of the users information."))
    {
        return View(db.GetAllUsers());
    }
    else if (await HttpContext.AuthorizePermission(name: "UnConfirmedUsers_Management", description: "Edit unconfirmed users information."))
    {
        return View(db.GetUnConfirmedUsers());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(new List<User>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Armin, Can I use this AuthorizePermission attribute on controller level?

Comment: Hi, @Alienalone, Sure you can. To get more instructions and clarification, you can review the **Usage** section of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it is working perfect for me. Thank you again